# How do I normalize a set of numbers from 0.95-1.0 to 1-10?

Tags: math, statistics

I have a table of similarity scores between 0.95 and 1.0, and i'd like to represent them as 1-10. How can I scale my data set to this range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All transformation from a (p-q) to (a-b) is a linear transformation, Linear transformation based on a Line Equation with this point:(p,a)&(q,b)-->(0.95,1)&(1,10)

```
Y=mX+d 

m=(b-a)/(q-p) :(10-1)/(1-0.95)=180
```

we have m and enough  to replace (p,a) or (q,b) in formula to gain d:

```
10=180*1+d => d=-170
```

so we have result equation :

**`Y=180X-170`**

Answer (score 1):

If a linear mapping is what you want, use the formula

```
180 * x - 170
```

where `x` is the value in the range 0.95 to 1.  This maps 0.95 tp 1 and 1 to 10.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract the lowest value of the range (0.95) and multiply by the scale (9 / 0.05 = 180):

```
update  YourTable
set     score = 1 + (score - 0.95) * 180
```

Comment: where did the `9` in `9/0.05` come from?

Comment: @Carson: it came from the same place as 0.05: 10-1=9, 1-0.95=0.05.